# Update IP status from Unused to Used Infoblox API

Tags: powershell, infobox

I am working on a script where I am creating VM and assigning available IP address to it given by concerned team. I need to integrate Infoblox API functionality with this

Once the IP is assigned,

1. I have to find the status of that particular IP address and

   - This part I got the request

> https://url/wapi/v2.10.5/ipv4address?ip_address=10.1.0.0

2. Update the status of that IP from **"Unused"** to **"Used"**.

Can you please help me with this. Need the API request to modify the status value against IP address

Sample API Response

```
    [
        {
            "_ref": "ipv4address/Li5pcHY0X2FkZHJlc3MkMTAuMTI0LjExLjIvMA:10.1.1.2",
            "ip_address": "10.1.1.2",
            "is_conflict": false,
            "mac_address": "",
            "names": [],
            "network": "10.1.1.0/7",
            "network_view": "default",
            "objects": [],
            "status": "UNUSED",
            "types": [],
            "usage": []
        }
    ]
```

I was trying a PUT request like below

````
```     https://url/wapi/v2.10.5/record:host/ZG5zLmhvc3QkLl9kZWZhdWx0LmNvbS5pbmZvLndhcGlhbGlhcw:10.124.11.2/default?_return_fields%2B=aliases&_return_as_object=1" -d '{"status": ["Used"]}'
```
````

but it is giving error

```
**{
"Error": "AdmConProtoError: Invalid value for _return_as_object: 1\" -d '{\"status\": [\"Used\"]}'",
"code": "Client.Ibap.Proto",
"text": "Invalid value for _return_as_object: 1\" -d '{\"status\": [\"Used\"]}'"
}**
```

Comment: If you assign that IP to a system, shouldn’t the status automatically switch to `USED`? I looked over their API and didn’t see an example of changing that status like you are trying.

Comment: @AdminOfThings:Currently team is doing the status change manually.

Comment: It looks like to me the `status` field is not an array. So I would not surround the value in `[]` in your `PUT` request.